# jQuery fixed image getting stuck on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, fade, scrolltop

http://rob.peytongregory.com/

If you go to that site and scroll down you'll see the logo image gets stuck when scrolling from one div to another. Im assuming it dues to my lack of jQuery knowledge. The image is fixed using css and fades using the jQuery.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('listen-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('music-player').play();
        });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height()*0.5)
            document.querySelector('#music-player').pause();
    });

    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(document).height()*0.3) {
            $("#music-player").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $("#music-player").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < $(document).height()*0.2) {
            $("#listen-btn").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $("#listen-btn").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < $(document).height()*0.39) {
            $(".main-logo").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $(".main-logo").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF IT WERE ME : I would try removing the logo div from its current containing divs,

Then set the logo div's "z-index" to higher than all the other divs, this way it is not dependent upon the fadein and fadeout effects